# php mysql insert update queries work locally but do not work on server

Tags: php, mysql

All kind of mysql queries working on locally, but when i try to run the insert and update queries from a php page on live server, it does not work and doesn't show any kind of error. My database connection is ok. I can fetch data from database. But i can't insert new data or update existing data from a php page.

Here is one of my queries:

```
<?php

session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['UserId'])){
    header("Location: index");
    die();
}
include("utility.php");

if(isset($_POST["btnEdit"]))
{
    $memberName = $_POST["memberName"];
    $designation = $_POST["designation"];

    $memberDetails = '';
    if(isset($_POST["memberDetails"])){
        $memberDetails = $_POST["memberDetails"];
    }
    $memberEmail = '';
    if(isset($_POST["memberEmail"])){
        $memberEmail = $_POST["memberEmail"];
    }

    $linkedin = '';
    if(isset($_POST["linkedin"])){
        $linkedin = $_POST["linkedin"];
    }

    $teamId = $_POST["teamId"];

    $result=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE team SET  memberName='".$memberName."', designation='".$designation."', memberDetails='".$memberDetails."', memberEmail='".$memberEmail."', linkedin='".$linkedin."' WHERE teamId='".$teamId."'");

    header("Location:team_member_list?id=".$teamId."&msg=Member Updated Successfully...)");
}
?>
```

Can someone kindly tell me what may be the reason?

Comment: does the mysql user(which you connected to database) have permissions to update/insert data?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: Yes, user have permission to update/insert data @devnullΨ

Comment: then check the mysql logs, try to run this query from mysql command line, dump your php code, check if it reaches your insert/update statements

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run those update/insert queries directly by manualy connecting to database and look for errors. But first, as devnull Ψ sad before, check your database user permissions.

Comment: I ran those queries directly in database. That time it executed successfully and showed me no error. I have checked repeatedly about user permissions.User have permissions for insert/update data.

Comment: Then check your php code, try to dump your final sql string. Maybe it has some bad values or quotes. And try enabling error_reporting(E_ALL);